# Поиск определенных символов в файле и удаление информации между ними

Tags: java

ребята. Помогите пож. Есть в файле вот такая строка

/*70a38*/

@include "\057h\157m\145/\156g\157r\151d\057n\147o\055r\151d\056c\157m\057w\167w\057c\157r\145/\143o\155p\157n\145n\164s\057t\151n\171m\143e\057.\0628\0631\1449\1432\056i\143o";

/*70a38*/ 
При том она разная в каждом файле. Задача ее найти и уничтожить. Подскажите пож, как это сделать оптимально.

ЗЫ Или намекните в какую сторону копать.

Спасибо.

Comment: Обычно последовательность такая: 1) считываете файл в строку 2) в строке вызываете замену строки, что нужно удалить на пустую строку, `text = text.replace("@include...", "")` 3) сохраняете строку в файл

Comment: Напишите парсер если вы знаете формат данных. Оптимально использовать прямой доступ к файлу. Можно поизучать редакторы, как они выкусывают куски текста из окна. В Eclipse вы можете написать такой редактор с помощью API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот два метода для чтения и записи в файл (накидал по-быстрому. Ищет вхождение "@include" строки):

```
private static String read(String fileName) {
    String res;
    boolean flag = false;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    try (BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
        while ((res = f.readLine()) != null)
            if (!(res.length() > 8 && res.substring(0, 8).equals("@include")))
                builder.append(res).append("\n");
            else
                flag = true; //искомая строка найдена
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Файл не найден");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка ввода вывода");
    }
    return flag ? builder.toString() : null;
}


private static void write(String fileName, String str) {
    if (str == null) {
        System.out.println("Передана пустая строка");
        return;
    }
    try (PrintWriter f = new PrintWriter(fileName)) {
        f.write(str);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Файл не найден");
    }
}
```

В методе main() вызовешь их так:

```
    String fileName = "Сюда пропишешь имя твоего файла";
    String str = read(fileName);
    write(fileName, str);
```